# Ошибка: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' (Googletrans)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-translate

Как исправить ошибку `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`, которая возникает при попытке перевода текста через googletrans (version = '3.0.0'). Срабатывает она не каждый раз, а в каком-то хаотичном порядке (Пикрил).

вот функция, в которой я перевожу текст:

```
from googletrans import Translator  # Библиотека для перевода текста
def translate(self):
    if self.can_translate:
        translator = Translator()
        in_text = self.inputText.toPlainText() # Текст из поля ввода
        in_lang = languages[self.inputLanguage.currentText()] # Язык с которого переводим (ru/en/...)
        out_lang = languages[self.outputLanguage.currentText()] # Язык на который переводим (ru/en/...)
        try:
            # Запрос к гугл переводчику и занесение текста в поле вывода
            print(in_text, in_lang, out_lang, "<---- Входные данные для перевода")
            result = translator.translate(in_text, src=in_lang, dest=out_lang)
            self.outputText.setPlainText(result.text)

            # Сохраняем перевод в БД и обновляем виджеты
            self.save_to_data_base()
            self.update_table_widgets()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e, "<---- Ошибка")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так понимаю, что это один из методов Вашего класса, а весь класс покажите, а то пример не воспроизводимый получается. И к тому, же googletrans не нужны указания языка оригинала, а направление перевода нужны только если язык на который переводится отличен от английского

Answer (score 1):

pip по умолчанию устанавлиает страую библиотеку googletranslate 3.0

нужно установить новую версию

```
pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
```

обратите внимание, эта версия не принимает списки. Только str...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась путем чтения гитхаба и танца с бубном. Для исправления ошибки я вынес инициализацию переводчика в `__init__(self)` и в функции `translate(self)` я инициализирую его заново до тех пор, пока он не перестанет выдавать ошибку.

**Код:**

```
def __init__(self):
       # Some code
       self.translator = Translator()
       # Some code

def translate(self):
    if self.can_translate:
        in_text = self.inputText.toPlainText() # Текст из поля ввода
        in_lang = languages[self.inputLanguage.currentText()] # Язык с которого переводим (ru/en/...)
        out_lang = languages[self.outputLanguage.currentText()] # Язык на который переводим (ru/en/...)
        while True:
            try:
                # Запрос к гугл переводчику и занесение текста в поле вывода
                result = self.translator.translate(in_text, src=in_lang, dest=out_lang)
                self.outputText.setPlainText(result.text)

                # Сохраняем перевод в БД и обновляем виджеты
                self.save_to_data_base()
                self.update_table_widgets()
                break

            except Exception as e:
                self.translator = Translator()
                print(e, "<---- Ошибка")
```